# Read specific XML node

Tags: c#

How can I select a specific node in my `XML` file ?

In my first `foreach` I select every `Property` that are inside my `Properties` tag, but I want a specific `Property`. A `Property` that has the `<PropertyCode>` equals 123 for example.

**XML**

```
<Carga>
    <Properties>
       <Property>
           <PropertyCode>122</PropertyCode>
           <Fotos>
               <Foto>
               </Foto>
           </Fotos>
       </Property>
       <Property>
           <PropertyCode>123</PropertyCode>
           <Fotos>
               <Foto>
               </Foto>
           </Fotos>
       </Property>
     </Properties>
</Carga>
```

**C# Code**

```
// Here I get all Property tag
// But i want to take just a specific one
foreach (XmlElement property in xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Carga/Properties/Property"))
{
   foreach (XmlElement photo in imovel.SelectNodes("Fotos/Foto"))
   {
       string photoName = photo.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
       string url = photo.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim();
       this.DownloadImages(property_id, url, photoName );
   }
}
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Linq to Xml](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx):

```
int code = 123;
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var property = xdoc.Descendants("Property")
                   .FirstOrDefault(p => (int)p.Element("PropertyCode") == code);

if (property != null)
{
    var fotos = property.Element("Fotos").Elements().Select(f => (string)f);
}
```

`fotos` will be collection of strings.

Comment: with `XMLDocument` can I do this ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos you can, but why would you? Linq to Xml gives you nice strongly-typed parsing

Comment: In a first moment I would like to work with `XMLDocument` because my `XML` file is far biggest than this sample that I put. So, when I update the version of my application, I can change to `XDocument`

Comment: @Lucas_Santos both XmlDocument and XDocument load whole file into memory. There is no benefit of XmlDocument usage. If file is really large, then you should use XmlReader

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: that is hardly strongly-typed parsing...   you can pass in any element name to search for and it might return null, and any object you get back is not typed - it's still just an XmlNode.  That's why you have to cast/convert the resulting element.

Comment: @MichaelBray agree with you (I kept in mind anonymous types selection when talked about stroingly-typing), but casting elements/attributes is much better than using Convert or Parse

Answer (score 1):

You can use a predicate expression in your XPath to pick out specific nodes..   something like this:

```
XmlNodeList nl = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Carga/Properties/Property[PropertyCode='123']/Fotos/Foto");
foreach(XmlNode n in nl) { ... }
```

See here for a quick reference to XPath syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: +1 from me, but I'd rather use XPath extensions for XDocument